# Variable in angularjs expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi guys I'm looking for a way to use variable in angularJS expression. Something like this :

`{{locale['static text' + variable]}}`

I've tried many ways include escape the quote, but it doesn't to work.

For more information:

`locale` is `$rootScope.locale` where I put the locale content depending language.

`variable` is `$scope.variable`

Comment: Ok - so, `locale` is an array and you are attempting to read a particular entry in this array using the index present in `variable`?

Comment: @callmekatootie yes, exactly :)

Comment: Doesn't @Aleksander's solution below work for you?

Comment: it works but what I want more is to inject some static text like in the question.

Comment: @vdt I've updated my plunkr, also with static text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{locale['static text' + variable]}}` works fine. See this Plunker for a [full example](http://plnkr.co/edit/k27t0n?p=preview):

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe.

**ng-bind-html-unsafe** will make the expression unquoted, that's why it is kind of unsafe.
A reminder, when working with ng directives, do not surround the expression with "{{}}".